# how to run "3gp, FLV, avi" video format in AVPLAYER or MPMoviePlayerViewController in iOS?

Tags: ios, video, ffmpeg, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayer

I need to play 3gp, FLV, avi Video file format in my application.
I had searched lot about it.

Got some library like "FFmpeg" Library. But could not find any sample code for it.

Any other ways for it are also appreciated.

Does any body have done it before?

I am even not sure that if it is possible or not in iOS.

Please give me solution for it.

**UPDATE :**

I tried one 3gp Video in my `AVquePlaye` but it is not play in my code,

While i use same Video in `WhatsApp` in my `iPhone`, Surprisingly video is playing there.

Answer (score 3):

I found out that playing 3gp in the SIMULATOR does not work (because on my mac it uses QuickTime which does not support 3gp, I guess).

When I run my app on a real device, it CAN play 3gp video, using the default video player. So be warned ;)