# AVPlayer does not play 3gp video format

Tags: ios12, swift5, xcode10.1

Is there a way to support `.3gp` format in AVPlayer? It does not seem to play it, while it plays any other format e.g., `.mov`, `.mp4`.

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)

let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerViewController.player = player

self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {                            
    playerViewController.player!.play()
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357721/known-issues-for-playing-3gp-videos-in-the-avplayer-framework?rq=1

Comment: It should work on the simulator, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30118680/4145420 Let me know if it's work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to run "3gp, FLV, avi" video format in AVPLAYER or MPMoviePlayerViewController in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26687735/how-to-run-3gp-flv-avi-video-format-in-avplayer-or-mpmovieplayerviewcontroll)